# Pattern matching with a predefined set in c#

Tags: c#, regex, .net-4.0

I just started learning pattern matching!

```
var stringToBeProcessed = "***???^^^^";
```

1. I have to check if this string **contains only [*, ?, ^]**
2. This string should not have 5 questions marks or 5 stars or 5 ^ **in a consecutive fashion(However they can be present distributively)**. 
   (ie) ***** or ????? or ^^^^^ is invalid.

   InValid Test cases:

**?????****???^^ // question is repeated 5 times consecutively, hence invalid.

%***       // a symbol other than [*, ?, ^] is present. hence invalid

**EDIT:**

I use string.Contains() method to check for the above patterns.

All i did was this:

```
string.contains("*****") || string.contains("^^^^^") || string.contains("?????") is true => is invalid
```

or

```
string.toCharArray().All(char => isCharIn(*,?,^)) is false => is invalid
```

The above way is bad because if the allowable symbols becomes huge, then my code also becomes huge. Any optimised but simple examples ?
A better way in Regex perhaps ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression like this:

```
^(([*?^])(?<!\2{5}))+$
```

The `\2` is a [back-reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thwdfzxy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which means it will match exactly what was previously matched in the second capture group (the character class). The `(?<!...)` is what's known as a [negative lookbehind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#zerowidth_negative_lookbehind_assertion), meaning it will reject any string where the preceding characters match the given pattern.

This will match any sequence of `*`, `?`, or `^` characters so long as it doesn't contain 5 consecutive instances of the same character.

For example:

```
Regex.IsMatch("***???^^^^", @"^(([*?^])(?<!\2{5}))+$");    // true
Regex.IsMatch("***???^^^^^", @"^(([*?^])(?<!\2{5}))+$");   // false
```

Comment: +1. thanks p.s.w.g. But, could you please help me by briefing it? I can then be able to roll out mine :). [Like what does this do `(?<!\2{5}))`) ? (I can understand that [*?^] denotes `allowable-characters`.

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed. See my updated answer for a more detailed explanation and provided some references. Just a word of warning, `[*?^]` is not the same as `[^?*]`, because `^` has special meaning inside a character class.

Comment: thanks a lot for guiding me through. Great answer. Will go through the references :)